# auto type deduction with container of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, auto

I don't understand why the compiler decided on pointer to in for the iterator itr in the 3rd for loop, instead of a pointer to a pointer as in the first 2 loops.  I tried to parse [the deduction rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) but couldn't find the relevant section.

```
void foo()
{
    vector<int*> a;
    int b[] =   { 1, 2, 3 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        a.push_back(&b[i]);
    }
    for (vector<int*>::iterator itr = a.begin(); itr != a.end(); ++itr)
    {
        //itr is a pointer to a pointer to an int
        cout << **itr << endl;
    }
    for (auto itr = a.begin(); itr != a.end(); ++itr)
    {
        //itr is a pointer to a pointer to an int
        cout << **itr << endl;
    }
    for (auto itr : a)
    {
        //itr is a pointer to an int.  Why?
        cout << *itr << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [range for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

> attr(optional) for ( range_declaration : range_expression ) loop_statement
>
> ...
>
> range_declaration - a declaration of a named variable, **whose type is
>   the type of the element of the sequence represented by
>   range_expression, or a reference to that type**. Often uses the auto
>   specifier for automatic type deduction

```
for (auto itr : a)
```

here `itr` gets the type of the elements in the `a`, namely `int*`.

You might write:

```
for (auto& itr : a)
```

and get a reference to the of the elements in the `a`, but there is no way to get a pointer to that type.

On the other hand, iterator represents a pointer-like entity, which points to the element of the container, that is why you use dereferencing twice: once to get a value of the element the iterator points to and has a type of `int*`, and second time to get the actual `int` value from `int*`.